# Selecting Timesheets

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to improve my SQL syntax, take the following for the example

```
SELECT * FROM `Users:Timesheets` 
WHERE 
`start` >= '{$monday}' 
AND `finish` <= '{$sunday}' 
AND `username` = '{$username}' 
AND `shift_type` = 'ONCALL'

OR 

`start` >= '{$monday}' 
AND `finish` IS NULL 
AND `username` = '{$username}' 
AND `shift_type` = 'ONCALL'

ORDER BY `id` ASC"
```

There must be a shorter way to achieve this or am I expecting too much?

Any insight to what I may be missing out on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two style comments, and one logic comment. The logic comment is the most significant.... you can rewrite your query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM `Users:Timesheets` 
WHERE 
      `start` >= '{$monday}' 
  AND (`finish` IS NULL OR `finish` <= '{$sunday}')
  AND `username` = '{$username}' 
  AND `shift_type` = 'ONCALL'
ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

Note, the style changes:

1. always put each SQL clause on it's own line (the FROM on a new line).
2. Try to indent each clause in the where clause so that the precedence of the logic is represented by the indentation.

**Update:** I assume, based on the variable syntax, and so on, that this SQL is not a direct query, but is rather the input to some string substitution that expands the `{$...}` variables. This is potentially vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Are you sure you shoud be running your SQL this way? Have you considered prepared statements? Is this a prepared statement?

Comment: Variables are well-cleansed and converted to true integers, booleans or strings before it gets to that part - Thank you for your assistance